# Creating a report in java using xml as datasource

Tags: java, crystal-reports, jasper-reports

I'm working on creating a PDF bill report in java. I tried crystal reports, jasper reports but they require database connectivity. I'm looking on how to create reports using XML as a datasource. If anyone has worked on this before please guide me on how to proceed.

Comment: Have you considered using BIRT (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIRT_Project) for your report design? You can specify XML data sources when creating data sources for your reports.

Answer (score 2):

Jasper reports don't need a database connection. They can use a collection of Java beans as their input. Transform the XML data source into custom Java objects or maps and pass them to a report.

Comment: The same is true for Crystal (well- i'm not sure about the beans)- i've only worked with .NET, but you can certainly pass an XML file as a datasource to a Crystal Report

Comment: @Boris : Problem with Jasper reports is that we dont have a good starter tutorial. I failed trying to search tutorials

Comment: @Chandu-Indyaah You can find a lot of samples in `$jasperreports$\demo\samples` folder from the JasperReports distribution package. You can also download the **`The JasperReports Ultimate Guide`**